# Mi mapa no muestra mi localización, ni el botón de mi localización. ¿Por Qué?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

He seguido un motón de vídeos y preguntas de este foro para implementarlo, pero por algún motivo que desconozco no me ubica en el mapa, ni tan siquiera aparece el `MyLocationButton`.
Mapa

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

Context context = this;
private GoogleMap mMap;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
Double latitud = 0.0;
Double longitud;
String titulo, descripcion, fecha;
Float dimension1 = 0.5f;
Float dimension2 = 0.5f;
Float opacidad = 1f;
int icono;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.activity_maps );
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager ()
            .findFragmentById ( R.id.map );
    mapFragment.getMapAsync ( this );

} // FIN METODO ONCREATE

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings ().setZoomControlsEnabled ( true );
    mMap.getUiSettings ().setMyLocationButtonEnabled ( true );

    final BBDD_Helper bbdd_helper = new BBDD_Helper ( context, BBDD_Helper.DATABASE_NAME, null, BBDD_Helper.DATABASE_VERSION );

    cargarPuntos ();




    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener ( new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {

            // ALERTDIALOG PARA ELEGIR ICONO
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder ( MapsActivity.this );
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext ().getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            final View row = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.row_item,null );
            ListView listView = (ListView)row.findViewById ( R.id.lvIconosMapa );
            listView.setAdapter ( new CustomAdapter ( getApplicationContext () ) );
            builder.setView ( row );

            // TITULO DEL ALERTDIALOG CUSTOMIZADO
            final TextView title = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
            title.setText("Elige una opción");
            title.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            title.setTextSize(20);
            builder.setCustomTitle(title);

            builder.setNegativeButton ( "Cancelar", null );
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
            dialog.show ();
            // FIN ALERTDIALOG

            listView.setOnItemClickListener ( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (position==0){
                        mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .title ( "Titulo" )
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (R.drawable.marihuana ) )
                                .anchor ( 0.5f,0.5f )
                                .snippet ( "Descripcion" )
                                .position ( latLng ));
                        Double latitud = latLng.latitude;
                        Double longitud = latLng.longitude;
                        fecha = String.valueOf ( Math.random () );
                        Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), DatosMarcas.class );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LATITUD", latitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LONGITUD", longitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "ICONO", R.drawable.marihuana );
                        intent.putExtra ( "FECHA", fecha);
                        startActivity ( intent);
                    }
                    else if (position==1){
                        mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (R.drawable.interes ) )
                                .title ( "Titulo" )
                                .anchor ( 0.0f,1.0f )
                                .snippet ( "Descripcion" )
                                .position ( latLng ));
                        Double latitud = latLng.latitude;
                        Double longitud = latLng.longitude;
                        fecha = String.valueOf ( Math.random () );
                        Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), DatosMarcas.class );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LATITUD", latitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LONGITUD", longitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "ICONO", R.drawable.interes );
                        intent.putExtra ( "FECHA", fecha);
                        startActivity ( intent);
                        dialog.cancel ();
                    }
                    else if (position==2){
                        mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (R.drawable.viogen_autor ) )
                                .title ( "Titulo" )
                                .anchor ( 0.0f,1.0f )
                                .snippet ( "Descripcion" )
                                .position ( latLng ));
                        Double latitud = latLng.latitude;
                        Double longitud = latLng.longitude;
                        fecha = String.valueOf ( Math.random () );
                        Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), DatosMarcas.class );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LATITUD", latitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LONGITUD", longitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "ICONO", R.drawable.viogen_autor );
                        intent.putExtra ( "FECHA", fecha);
                        startActivity ( intent);
                        dialog.cancel ();
                    }
                    else if (position==3){
                        mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
                                .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource (R.drawable.viogen ) )
                                .title ( "Titulo" )
                                .anchor ( 0.0f,1.0f )
                                .snippet ( "Descripcion" )
                                .position ( latLng ));
                        Double latitud = latLng.latitude;
                        Double longitud = latLng.longitude;
                        fecha = String.valueOf ( Math.random () );
                        Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), DatosMarcas.class );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LATITUD", latitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "LONGITUD", longitud );
                        intent.putExtra ( "ICONO", R.drawable.viogen );
                        intent.putExtra ( "FECHA", fecha);
                        startActivity ( intent);
                        dialog.cancel ();
                    }
                }

            } );

        }


    } );

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener ( new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener () {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder ( MapsActivity.this );
            LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext ().getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

            // TITULO DEL ALERTDIALOG CUSTOMIZADO
            final TextView title = new TextView(MapsActivity.this);
            title.setText(marker.getTitle ());
            title.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            //     title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            title.setTextSize(20);
            latitud = marker.getPosition ().latitude;
            builder.setMessage ( marker.getSnippet () );
            builder.setCustomTitle(title);
            builder.setPositiveButton ( "Eliminar marca", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = bbdd_helper.getWritableDatabase ();
                    String marcaBorrar = marker.getTitle ();
                    String [] argumento = {marcaBorrar};
                    String seleccion = BBDD_Helper.C_COLUMNA_NOMBRE + " LIKE ?";
                    db.delete ( BBDD.BBDD_Estructura.TABLE_NAME, seleccion, argumento );
                    Toast.makeText ( MapsActivity.this,"La marca ha sido borrada correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();
                    Cursor c = db.query ( BBDD.BBDD_Estructura.TABLE_NAME,
                            null,null,null,null,null,null);
                    int tamaño = c.getCount ();
                    googleMap.clear ();
                    cargarPuntos ();

                }



            } );
            builder.setNegativeButton ( "Cerrar", null );

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create ();
            dialog.show ();
            // FIN ALERTDIALOG
            // marker.showInfoWindow ();
            return true;
        }
    } );

}

private void setMarker(LatLng posicion, String titulo, String descripcion, float opacidad, float dimesion1, float dimension2, int icono){
    mMap.addMarker ( new MarkerOptions ()
            .position ( posicion )
            .title ( titulo )
            .snippet ( descripcion )
            .alpha ( opacidad )
            .anchor ( dimesion1,dimension2 )
            .icon ( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource ( icono )));

}

private void cargarPuntos (){
    BBDD_Helper bbdd_helper = new BBDD_Helper ( context, BBDD_Helper.DATABASE_NAME, null, BBDD_Helper.DATABASE_VERSION);
    db = bbdd_helper.getReadableDatabase ();
    Cursor c = db.query(
            BBDD.BBDD_Estructura.TABLE_NAME,  // Nombre de la tabla
            null,  // Lista de Columnas a consultar
            null,  // Columnas para la cláusula WHERE
            null,  // Valores a comparar con las columnas del WHERE
            null,  // Agrupar con GROUP BY
            null,  // Condición HAVING para GROUP BY
            null  // Cláusula ORDER BY
    );
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
        do {
            latitud= c.getDouble (2);
            longitud = c.getDouble(3);
            titulo = c.getString ( 1 );
            descripcion = c.getString ( 4 );
            icono = c.getInt ( 5 );
            setMarker ( new LatLng (latitud,longitud  ), titulo,descripcion, opacidad,dimension1,dimension2, icono  );
        } while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close ();

    if (latitud!=0.0){
        CameraUpdate camUpd1 =
                CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitud,longitud), 15);
        mMap.moveCamera(camUpd1);}}
}
```

Permisos Manifest

```
  android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  android.permission.INTERNET
  android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
  android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
    com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

Comment: Hola, en que versión de android estás instalando tu APP?

Comment: Hola lo he probado en el emulador y en mi móvil. Ambos con la api25. Android 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios puntos a considerar:

1.- Hay que habilitar la función **setMyLocationEnabled**

```java
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled (true);
```

- Nota: Si compilas en una versión inferior a la 6 o API 23 no debes tener inconvenientes, pero... ahí entra a tallar el punto número 2.

2.- A partir de las versión 6 en adelante cambia las políticas sobre los permisos, hay que verificar los permisos e informar al usuario si va a brindar los accesos correspondientes:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Adjunto una guía:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // A partir de las versión 6 en adelante cambia las políticas sobre los permisos
        // Hay que verificar los permisos e informar al usuario si va a brindar los accesos correspondientes

        // Validamos la versión
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            // Validamos si ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION tiene permisos otorgados por el usuario
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Informamos al usuario sobre que permisos se le van a solicitar.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  }, MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                return;
            } else {
                // Esta parte se ejecuta cuando los permisos son otorgados por el usuario
                getMap();
            }
        } else {
            // Esta bloque se ejecuta cuando una versión de android es inferior a la 6 o API 23, obtiene la información sobre los permisos
            // del AndroidManifest.xml
            getMap();
        }

    }

    private void getMap() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled (true);

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // Si el usuario acepta los permisos
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getMap();
                } else {
                    // Si el usuario no brinda los permisos
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permiso denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Funciona!! Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Para ver mi ubicación y obtener la latitud, longitud, hice lo siguiente:

```
    private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        setLocation(location);
        agregarMarcador(lat, lng);
    }
}

LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        actualizarUbicacion(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        mensaje = "GPS Activado";
        mensaje();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        mensaje = "GPS desactivado";
     //   locationStart();
        mensaje();
    }
};
```

**Aquí agregamos el marcador recibiendo los parámetros de latitud y longitud del método actualizarUbicacion**

```
private void agregarMarcador(double lat, double lng) {
    LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 16);

    if (marcador != null) marcador.remove();

    marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(coordenadas)
            .title(direccion));

}
```

Y el location Manager con los permisos:

```
    private void locationStart() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        return;
    }
}
```